# Ajax datatable not reloadiing in codeigniter 3.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am using Codigniter 3.0
and i have a page where i am listing my all the customer with the ajax datatable feature.

I have used the following code.

http://mbahcoding.com/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-modal-server-side-validation.html

Here is the download link for above example
http://www.mediafire.com/download/elmnr3m2kugdkh8/ajax_crud_datatables_with_validation_update5.zip

My problem is after creating a new customer or updating any customer information my datatable is not reloading.  it does not create any error in console but it display "Processing" and nothing, 
I checked in the console. it is getting fresh data but its not rendering /updating the data.

i tried so many code to update like

```
$('#sample_2').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();
$("#sample_2").api().ajax.reload();
table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax  // var table = $("$sample2"); here
table.api().draw();
```

is that can be a datatable version issue ?

even searching is also not working.

**Here is my Controller :**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Experts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();

        //Check Validation
        checkAdminValidate();        

        // Load Admin Experts Model
        $this->load->model('Adminexperts_model','experts');
    }   

    /*
    * @function : index
    * @date-created : 19th Auth 2016
    * @autor : Punit Gajjar
    * @purpose : To render the all the list of the experts
    */
    public function index()
    {

        $data['content'] = 'insoadmin/experts';        
        $this->load->view("insoadmin/insoadmin_master" , $data); // redering the View
    }   

    /*
    * @function : getExperts
    * @date-created : 19th Auth 2016
    * @autor : Punit Gajjar
    * @purpose : To get the list of all the experts for Datatable
    */    
    public function ajax_list(){

        $list = $this->experts->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];


        foreach ($list as $experts) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            /*
            $row[] = '<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="experts[]" value="'.$experts->expert_id.'" />
                            <span></span>
                        </label>';
                        */
            $row[] = $experts->first_name;
            $row[] = $experts->email_address;
            $row[] = $experts->skype_id;
            $row[] = $experts->skype_id;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_experts('."'".$experts->expert_id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_experts('."'".$experts->expert_id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw" => "1",
            "recordsTotal" => $this->experts->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->experts->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);

    }

    public function ajax_edit($id)
    {
        $data = $this->experts->get_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function ajax_add()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'skype_id' => $this->input->post('skype_id'),
            );
        $insert = $this->experts->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_update()
    {        
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'skype_id' => $this->input->post('skype_id'),
            );
        $this->experts->update(array('expert_id' => $this->input->post('id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_delete($id)
    {
        $this->experts->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }


    private function _validate()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['error_string'] = array();
        $data['inputerror'] = array();
        $data['status'] = TRUE;

        if($this->input->post('first_name') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'first_name';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'First name is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('last_name') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'last_name';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Last name is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('skype_id') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'skype_id';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Skype Id is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($data['status'] === FALSE)
        {
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

**Here is my Model :**

```
<?php
class Adminexperts_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'tbl_experts';
    var $column_order = array('first_name','last_name','skype_id','email_address','created_date','modified_date','status'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('first_name','last_name','skype_id','email_address','created_date','modified_date','status'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 
    var $order = array('expert_id' => 'asc'); // default order 

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('expert_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('expert_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

}
```

**Here is my View :**

```
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/global/css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->

<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
    <div class="page-content">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEAD-->
        <div class="page-head">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1>Managed Datatables
                    <small>managed datatable samples</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE TOOLBAR -->
            <div class="page-toolbar">
                <!-- BEGIN THEME PANEL -->
                <div class="btn-group btn-theme-panel">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-settings"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu theme-panel pull-right dropdown-custom hold-on-click">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <h3>HEADER</h3>
                                <ul class="theme-colors">
                                    <li class="theme-color theme-color-default active" data-theme="default">
                                        <span class="theme-color-view"></span>
                                        <span class="theme-color-name">Dark Header</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="theme-color theme-color-light " data-theme="light">
                                        <span class="theme-color-view"></span>
                                        <span class="theme-color-name">Light Header</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 seperator">
                                <h3>LAYOUT</h3>
                                <ul class="theme-settings">
                                    <li> Layout
                                        <select class="layout-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="fluid" selected="selected">Fluid</option>
                                            <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Header
                                        <select class="page-header-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="fixed" selected="selected">Fixed</option>
                                            <option value="default">Default</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Top Dropdowns
                                        <select class="page-header-top-dropdown-style-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="light">Light</option>
                                            <option value="dark" selected="selected">Dark</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Sidebar Mode
                                        <select class="sidebar-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                                            <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Sidebar Menu
                                        <select class="sidebar-menu-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="accordion" selected="selected">Accordion</option>
                                            <option value="hover">Hover</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Sidebar Position
                                        <select class="sidebar-pos-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="left" selected="selected">Left</option>
                                            <option value="right">Right</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                    <li> Footer
                                        <select class="page-footer-option form-control input-small input-sm">
                                            <option value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                                            <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END THEME PANEL -->
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE TOOLBAR -->
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE HEAD-->
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE BREADCRUMB -->
        <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tables</a>
                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="active">Datatables</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END PAGE BREADCRUMB -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
                <div class="portlet light portlet-fit portlet-datatable bordered">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class=" icon-layers font-green"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-green sbold uppercase">Experts List</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default" href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default" href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="icon-wrench"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default" href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <br />
                        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reload_table()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Reload</button>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover order-column" id="sample_2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Expert Name </th>
                                    <th> Email </th>
                                    <th> Skype Id </th>
                                    <th> Status </th>
                                    <th> Action </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE BASE CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT BODY -->
</div>



<!-- Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Expert Form</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
                <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Skype Id</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="skype_id" placeholder="Skype Id" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- End Bootstrap modal -->

<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->


<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = $('#sample_2');

    table.dataTable({

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('insoadmin/experts/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });

    var tableWrapper = jQuery('#sample_2_wrapper');

    table.find('.group-checkable').change(function () {
        var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
        var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
        jQuery(set).each(function () {
            if (checked) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });


    //set input/textarea/select event when change value, remove class error and remove text help block 
    $("input").change(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).next().empty();
    });
    $("textarea").change(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).next().empty();
    });
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).next().empty();
    });

    function add_experts()
    {
        save_method = 'add';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
        $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Expert'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
    }

    function edit_experts(id)
    {
        save_method = 'update';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
        $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

        //Ajax Load data from ajax
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('insoadmin/experts/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {

                $('[name="id"]').val(data.expert_id);
                $('[name="first_name"]').val(data.first_name);
                $('[name="last_name"]').val(data.last_name);
                $('[name="skype_id"]').val(data.skype_id);

                $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Expert'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
    }

    function reload_table()
    {
        //$('#sample_2').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();
        //$("#sample_2").api().ajax.reload();
        table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax 
        //table.api().draw();
    }

    function save()
    {
        $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
        var url;

        if(save_method == 'add') {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('insoadmin/experts/ajax_add')?>";
        } else {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('insoadmin/experts/ajax_update')?>";
        }

        // ajax adding data to database
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                {
                    $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                    reload_table();
                }
                else
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                    {
                        $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                        $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                    }
                }
                $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
                $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

            }
        });
    }

    function delete_experts(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Are you sure delete this expert?'))
        {
            // ajax delete data to database
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('insoadmin/experts/ajax_delete')?>/"+id,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //if success reload ajax table
                    $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                    reload_table();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error deleting data');
                }
            });

        }
    }

</script>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello please check your persons.php in controller
there you have used the format like

```
$row[] = $person->firstName;
$row[] = $person->lastName;
$row[] = $person->gender;
$row[] = $person->address;
$row[] = $person->dob;
```

Please change it to

```
$row[] = $person->firstname;
$row[] = $person->lastname;
$row[] = $person->gender;
$row[] = $person->address;
$row[] = $person->dob;
```

Let us know it works or not. After changing it. I can have the updated table

Please add "bStateSave": true,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],
        "bStateSave": true,
    });
```

As per your scenario the search will work after adding the bStateSave. You can also refer to the search API documentation which is provided here https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()
This will help you more in understanding. How my answer helped you out.

Comment: i have different fields , i am using $row[] = $person->email_address;
            $row[] = $person->skype_id;

Comment: Can you update your actual controller, model and error message it may be displayed in console. So that we can have a proper look.

Comment: Hello @Vivek , Reload started working now,. But searching is still not working .

Comment: @PunitGajjar Has the update answer helped you out. Please add your inputs so other users can get help.

Comment: Nope , "bStateSave": true, dosen't work but i found the issue just now that  i needed to use  "draw" => $_post['draw'] , instead of "draw" => "1" in my controller.  Then i used $('#sample_2').dataTable().api().ajax.reload() instead of $('#sample_2').ajax.reload(); which was working good as expectation .

Thanks for the try mate.